# VB ASP.NET webforms app: compile error on code that does not exist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I get an error:

> C:\Users\XXX\Source\Repos\XXX\Src\XXX\Admin\ClientCare\XXX.aspx(4) : error BC30205: End of statement expected.

here:

```
__o = Session("State"))
```

This code does not actually exist in my page; it's autogenerated somewhere by ASP.NET. But it has an extra right parenthesis which is causing the compile error. How can I fix this error? It doesn't occur in Visual Studio, only when I run the app.

Comment: Replace the page? Delete it (save it somewhere), compile, replace? Looks like it's in source ctrl.

Comment: Oh, hang on, I found `__o = Session("State")` but with only one right parenthesis in the code... wonder where the second one is coming from?